# get object before create it , is it possible

Tags: c++

Is it possible to get the object before create the object itself?

like this

```
template <class T>
class Event {
protected:
    T*Obj ; 
public:
    void onclick() { Obj->getobject()->dosomthing ; }  // i need help how to get the object
};

class myclass : public Event<myclass> {
public:
    Event<myclass>* getobject() {return Obj;}
    myclass* createobject() ; 
};
```

I try a few codes and ideas but it always fails and I get nothing ( null pointer )

I try pointer to member, and pointer to function but it fails too!
I don't now if I explain what I want exactly.

Any help?

Here is the full code

```
template <class T>
class GUI_Event
{
private:
    static bool _Donothing (const EventArgs &Args) {return false ; }
    T*Obj ;

protected:

    /*for window only*/

    bool ( *CloseClicked )                     (const EventArgs &Args) ;
    /* event fired on left mouse click*/
    bool ( *_L_Mouse_Click_DoFunction )        (const EventArgs &Args) ;
    /* event fired on right mouse click*/
    bool ( *_R_Mouse_Click_DoFunction )        (const EventArgs &Args) ; 
    /*event  fired on middle mouse click*/
    bool ( *_M_Mouse_Click_DoFunction )        (const EventArgs &Args) ; 



public:



    /*set up fired function on left mouse click event*/

    const void Set_L_Mouse_Click_DoFunction( bool (*Function)(const EventArgs &Args))  {this->_L_Mouse_Click_DoFunction = NULL ; 
                                                                                           this->_L_Mouse_Click_DoFunction = Function ;
                                            Obj->Get_FrameWindowPtr ()->subscribeEvent ( FrameWindow::EventMouseClick , CEGUI::Event::Subscriber ( &_L_Mouse_Click_DoFunction ));} 

    /*set up fired function on right mouse event click */

};

class GUI_Window : public GUI_Event<GUI_Window>
{


private:


    static void SetID() ;
    /*
    Identifie Number For The Window
    */
    static int ID ; 

    /*
    /the Identifir Number for current window
    */
        int Wnd_ID ; 
        //Frame WIndow 
        CEGUI::FrameWindow        *_Frame_Window ;





        /* Window Name == value by the user */
        CEGUI::String             *_Window_Name ;


        /*window type == for now is inluded ( XML FIle (without extension)/FrameWindow )*/
        CEGUI::String             *_Window_Type;



        /* XML File that include style of the GUI   */
        String                    *_File_Name; 






public:

/*  create a Window */
        explicit GUI_Window ( CL_HUD const*Hud , String const&Window_Name );
        /*  create a Window */
        explicit GUI_Window ( const CL_HUD &Hud , String const&Window_Name );


    /*
    return current framewindow As Pointer 
    */
    FrameWindow              *const Get_FrameWindowPtr ()const                      { return _Frame_Window ; }
        /*
    return current framewindow 
    */
    const FrameWindow        &Get_FrameWindow ()const                               { return *_Frame_Window ; }





    /*return current window type*/
    const String            &Get_WindowType()  const                               { return *_Window_Type ;}
    /*return current window type As Pointer */
    String                  *const Get_WindowTypePtr()  const                      { return _Window_Type ;}



    /*return current window name As Pointer  */
    String                   *const Get_WindowNamePtr()  const                     { return _Window_Name ;}
    /*return current window name*/
    const String             &Get_WindowName()  const                              { return *_Window_Name ;}


    /* return XML File Name Scheme */
    const String             &Get_File_Name()  const                               { return *_File_Name ;}
    /* return XML File Name Scheme As Pointer */
    String                   *const Get_File_NamePtr()  const                      { return _File_Name ;}


    void SetText(String text )                        { Get_FrameWindowPtr ()->setText ( text ); *_Window_Name = text ; }
    int Get_ID ()                                                                  { return Wnd_ID ; }
    ~GUI_Window();


};
```

The problem is that I get a null pointer in this following line

```
Set_L_Mouse_Click_DoFunction
```

Comment: It's not clear what you want to accomplish, clearly indicated by the three different answers you've had by now. PS: Perhaps explaining how you would use this would make it easier to give an appropriate answer.

Comment: Posting a "wall of code" rarely helps get better answers. If anything, it causes people to just skip the question altogether. Try to post a small piece of code that reproduces the problem. Sometimes you can even figure out the problem yourself just by doing that.

Comment: Google "C++ lazy initialization" may turn up something useful for you otherwise question could use clarification and a more concise example code.

Answer (score 1):

Long short answer: Yes.  But your object won't have been created so when you 'get' it it will be null, and if you use it bad things will probably happen.

Short long answer: What?

```
class Event
{
public:
bool onclick()
    { getobject->dosomthing ; }  //// getobject is a method.
                                 //// It should have parenthases
};

class myclass : public  Event
{
private:
Obj ;                  //// This is odd.  What is Obj?
                       //// Is it supposed to be a type or a variable name?
                       //// a line like the following would create the object on the stack:
                       //// myclass Obj;
 public:

  getobject() {return Obj;}
  createobject() ; 
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use *inheritance*:

```
class Event
{
public:
    virtual bool onclick() { /* default behavior here */ }
    virtual ~Event() { } // virtual destructor for a base class.
}

class MyClass : public Event
{
public:
    MyClass() { myObj = new Obj(); }

    bool onclick() { myObj->DoSomething(); }

    ~MyClass() { delete myObj; }
private:
    Obj* myObj;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean [Lazy Loading](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_loading) your objects?

Answer (score 0):

i answer my question like this

```
set_Object (T*newObj)     {Obj = newObj ; }
```

in GUI_Window i do

```
set_Object(this)
```